# Передача функции массива элементов

Tags: javascript

```
Element.prototype.myfunc=function(){ /*...*/ }
document.getElementById('myID').myfunc();
```

Функция *myfunc* сработает, если ей передать элемент. А как быть, если нужно передать массив элементов? Например:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').myfunc();
```

Т.е., что изменить в Element.prototype.myfunc=function(){ ..... } , когда не знаешь, будет ли ей передан элемент или массив? Я так понимаю, вместо *Element* нужно написать что-то типа *Object*, но тогда функция не заработает, если передаваться будет один элемент.

Comment: очевидно же, что нужно добавить эту функцию в `NodeList.prototype`

Comment: плохо с этим знаком, читал доки и чёт не понял, можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

> я так понимаю за место Element нужно написать что то типа Object

напишите `NodeList`:

```
NodeList.prototype.myfunc=function(){ ..... }
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: @shol: приведёте минимальный пример? (лучше на jsfiddle)

Comment: вот пример 

function cen(a) { 
a.style.left = document.body.clientWidth / 2 - (add.offsetWidth / 2); a.style.top = document.body.clientHeight / 2 - (add.offsetHeight / 2); 
}
NodeList.prototype.cent=function(){ cen(this); return this; } - так не работает
а так Element.prototype.cent=function(){ cen(this); return this; } работает, но если  так то как же быть если функции передаться не элемент а массив например

Comment: проблема в том, что я функции может передаться как массив так и просто элемент

Comment: вы сами говорите "массив элементов", а работаете как с единичным элементом, т.е. в случае с `NodeList` пройдитесь по `this` в цикле, из этого следует, что вы взяли себе задачу не по знаниям, может стоит обратиться к тематической литературе

Comment: если массив то всё норм, а вот если просто элемент то не работает... я же говорю, может быть просто элемент, а может быть массив

Comment: Object.prototype.ce=function(){ var b = this; for (var m = 0; m < b.length; m++) { cen(b[m]); } return this; }
Element.prototype.ce=function(){ cen(this); return this; }

Comment: но так как то не правильно, но работает

Comment: в общем чем заменить эту запись?

Object.prototype.ce=function(){ var b = this; for (var m = 0; m < b.length; m++) { cen(b[m]); } return this; } Element.prototype.ce=function(){ cen(this); return this; }

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').myfunc();
```

Может я уже не в теме но где здесь в функцию передается хоть что-то?
Вызов функции myfunc() - это скобочки, и все что в них это параметры!

То что слева от функции это контекс вызова, в данном случае смысл в том что внутри тела функции myfunc() значение `this будет результатом вызова document.getElementsByTagName('*')` и в данном случае это будет массивоподобная коллекция элементов.

А вот внутри функции можно проверить контекст и что-нибудь сделать либо с каждым элементом коллекции, либо на всей коллекцией:

```
context.myfunc(){
    if(this.length){ // скорее всего это коллекция
        for(var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; ++n){
           var elem = this[i];
           elem....
        }
    }
    else { // конкретный элемент
        var elem = this;
        elem....
    }
}
```

Вообще это манера программирования в стиле jquery. И советую с этими вещами разобраться.

**Дополнение после комментария.**

И правда не стой стороны начал, такие вещи (добавление/изменение свойств и методов встроенным объектам) необходимо делать только в случаях крайней нужды (в современных книгах пишут например если не хватает какого-то метода, но его обязательно добавят в новой версии браузера, то для совместимости).

Лучше сделать так

```
function myfunc(v){
    if(v.length){ // скорее всего это коллекция
        for(var i = 0, n = v.length; i < n; ++n){
            var elem = this[i];
            elem....
        }
    }
    else { // конкретный элемент
        var elem = v;
        elem....
    }
}

myfunc(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));
```

Comment: да не, там собрались любители переписывать встроенные объекты, а потом удивляться.